# StringIndexOutOfBounds by -3

Tags: java

I have inherited a project that should work. However, the original coder is unavailable.

I'm getting `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The stack trace goes to this line:

```
int lserver_num = Integer.parseInt(MOTD.substring(MOTD.indexOf("-") + 1, MOTD.indexOf(" ")));
```

Suggestions?

Comment: post all of your code not just the problem line. I'd guess the issue lies in the bounds you are using for a loop or the index you are using for the substring call

Comment: Do you have some sample strings that would represent the value stored in MOTD? From quick glance it would appear that one of your .indexOf calls is returning -1 and substring cannot be created on a negative value.

Comment: Please include the whole code. Since you are getting an index out of bounds exception, it is because you are trying to access something that is outside of your string's length (obviously). Make sure that your string and the way your parser work are proper.

Comment: Did you Google this to make an effort to understand what this exception is and why it might be happening on a `substring` call? With that information, you should be able to debug this and figure it out yourself. You haven't posted nearly enough information for us to help you.

Comment: If  doesn't " " exist in MOTD then it will return -1 which will give you this error ! or if the last character in the string is "-" then it will also throw this error ! Good luck trying to figure it out !

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to substring by a value greater than the string's length or less than 0. If you provide more code, it would be easier to diagnose your problem exactly. But as you haven't, I have to assume.

Here is an example:

```
String test = "123-2 ";
int i = Integer.parseInt(test.substring(test.indexOf("-") + 1, test.indexOf(" ")));
System.out.println(i);
```

When I run it, it prints out 2, no problem. If I remove the space from the string, it gives me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -5` I dont know how it arrives at -5, but I can see that the string is 5 characters long without the space, so I guess it defaults to the strings length if it cant find the character, maybe?

From this, I have to ask: are you sure that the string contains a `blank space` or a `hyphen` ?

Check with

```
if (MOTD.contains(" ") && MOTD.contains("-")
```

Also it would be good to do a null check to see if MOTD is null first.

Comment: MOTD does contain a hypen.

Comment: Is MOTD part of an external file being read in? is MOTD defind in the code? I have had to do alot of guessing in my answer... could you please provide more code than just the error line in your original post?

Comment: MOTD is defined by an External .yml file. I set it to US-1 and there are several if statements mentioning "US-1" so I know that it is the correct value